# Can I swap 2 identical source files in Power BI?

Tags: excel, powerbi

I have to do monthly reports in Excel and then present them in Power BI. Can I swap the source files in Power BI without manually changing each field for each chart?

Comment: Being you have an Excel tag, I'll assume Excel and PowerBI Desktop.  Have you looked at View, Advanced Editor from the Query Editor?  Editing the Source line may be what you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes! You can!

In the drop down for 'Edit Queries' or, in-side 'Edit Queries', look for Data source settings.

There you can change the source file. Don't forget to 'Refresh' the data afterwards!

The only thing you'll have to look out for is field-names/tab-names/field-types changing. If any of those have changed, you may need to either edit the applied steps or dig in to the advanced query for further changes.